# Align two divs those are on different side

Tags: html, css

I'm new to CSS and HTML and my question is very simple!

I have three `<div>` tags in my page like this :

```
<div id="first"> foo </div>
<div id= "second"> foo </div>
<div id= "third"> foo </div>
```

I'd like to show my divs like this :

```
<div id="first"> foo </div>
<div id= "second"> foo </div>  <div id= "third"> foo </div>
```

I'd like to move third  on right side and align with second  in order to be in same line!

How can I do it?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/geUpb/1 like this?

Answer (score 2):

Use a combination of the `float` and `clear` properties:

```
<style>
#first, #second, #third { float:left; }
#second { clear:left; }

/* width is not necessary. added for display purposes */
#second, #third { width:50%; } 
</style>

<div id="first"> foo </div>
<div id= "second"> foo </div>
<div id= "third"> foo </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8d7tD/

Comment: You can get the same results with a little less code: `#second, #third {
    float:left;
    width:50%;
}`

Comment: @j08691 right. but, what if the width is not `50%`, say `33%`? `float`ing & `clear`ing resolves this. the op didn't specify width's, i introduced it for display purposes in the example provided.

Comment: Hmm.. I want for example, image that both second and third divs are box, and fist is some text. I'd like to align that always second and third boxes be align by horizontal line independent of first div!

Answer (score 0):

Here's another possibility (there are a lot of ways of doing it - not sure if there is an established "best way" it really depends on the rest of the page).

**Updated based on comments:**

#### HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="first">foo</div>
    <div id="second">foo</div>
    <div id="third">foo sadsad asdasdasd asdasdasa</div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
/*just for display purposes*/
 #first, #second, #third {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width:100px;
}
#container {
    position: relative;
    width: 210px;
}
#first {
    height:100px;
}
#third {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Here is a demo: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GXqvq/)

It should be noted that you will likely need a `clear:both` somewhere after using this.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/f7uMP/1/ take a look this! I'd like to align in every case  bottom from second div with third bottom line

Comment: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/klulf1q9xucghta/Screen%20Shot%202013-07-15%20at%2012.47.48%20PM%20%282%29.png)

Comment: @prog.Dusan Ok, I updated it. Is that what you are looking for?